# Mobile Nav, click through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've built a simple mobile `nav` which works to some extent, but once you get to the link that actually goes to a page, the JavaScript that runs the functions prevents the action from happening, does this make sense?

I have a `prevent default` on `a` tags to show the sub menus and as a result of this the page link isn't actually clickable, here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rzvwb113/2/)

```
$('.mobile-nav ul.parent-level > li.has-submenu').on('click',function(e){
    $('ul.level-one').css('left', 0);
    e.preventDefault();
});
$('.mobile-nav ul.level-one > li').on('click',function(e){
    if( !$(this).hasClass('back-title') ){
        $(this).find('ul.level-two').css('left', 0);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
$('.mobile-nav li.back-title').on('click',function(e){
    //alert('go back');
    $(this).parent().css('left', '100vw' );
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need the preventDefault()? You actually have the prevent default on the li's rather than than a tags, which actually won't do anything adverse that you need to prevent will it?

I've removed the

`e.preventDefault();`

lines and the links in the submenus now become clickable - seemingly with no adverse affect on the rest of the menus. Have a look see if you agree...

http://jsfiddle.net/rzvwb113/3/